# Intellij Idea - automatically add final keyword to the generated variables

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The new introduced code convention require to use the "final" keyword where possible.

The question is - is there a possibility to automatically generate the variables with this keyword ? For example - I select a code fragment:

```
"bla"+"bla"+"bla"
```

and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> - the IDE generates a variable like this:

```
String blaString = "bla"+"bla"+"bla";
```

but I need it to be

```
final String blaString = "bla"+"bla"+"bla";
```

P.S. I know about inspections and the possibility "fix them all", but it can't be used everywhere as there is a lot of old code that shouldn't be refactored without reason.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Go to Settings/Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Code Generation and enable "Make generated local variables final" and "Make generated parameters final" in the "Final modifier" section. You can also try searching for "final" in preferences.

Comment: And, you can also export those settings and share them with your colleagues.

Comment: It would be great if they added the same for field members :)

Comment: Tere is an open issue for that here - http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-31585 log in and upvote it

Answer (score 55):

In IntelliJ 14.1.3

1. **`Preferences`** > **`Editor`** > **`Code Style`** > **`Java`**
2. To the far right ,there's a tab called **`Code Generation`**
3. In the section called **`Final Modifier`** there are two choices:

   - Make generated local variables final
   - Make generated parameters final

Answer (score 7):

After selecting "introduce local variable" there is a little gear to the right of the variable name. Click that and check "Declare final". That variable will be marked as final and Intellij will remember your preference until changed.

Comment: Thank you! The Code Style setting is apparently unrelated to this.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows User;

Go to  **`File`** -> **`Settings`** -> **`Editor`** -> **`Code Style`** -> Select Preferred Language (**`Java`**) ->  **`Checkbox`** -> Make generated local variables final, Make generated parameters final
-> **`Apply`** -> **`OK`**

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to disable this behavior from the Code Style settings, but Steven Bayer's solution worked for me. I'm providing a screenshot for clarity on what he's referring to. Uncheck the "Declare final" box.

[image]